# Automatic Domain Join

Tags: powershell, join, dns

i want to automate the domain join.

The admin should define in which OU the Computer will be assigned.

Therefore i used a Listbox.

The result should be compared with the predifined variables for the spezific distinguished Name of the OUs and write the string in a variable to use it in the following command:

```
Add-Computer -ComputerName $hostname -DomainName "domain.de" -OUPath $OUpathVariable
```

I dont know how to compare the result with the predefined variables of the spezific OUs and how i get them in the command above.

I could use many if-loops like that - but there has to be a much smarter way i guess.

```
if ($OU_result -eq $OU_1)
{
Add-Computer -ComputerName $hostname -DomainName "domain.de" -OUPath $OU_1
}

if ($OU_result -eq $OU_2)
{
Add-Computer -ComputerName $hostname -DomainName "domain.de" -OUPath $OU_2
}

if ($OU_result -eq $OU_3)
{
Add-Computer -ComputerName $hostname -DomainName "domain.de" -OUPath $OU_3
}
```

**the hostname will be predifed in a seperatly

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'AD-OU?'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,360)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,290)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(188,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'Start DomainJoin'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(205,290)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(65,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Select Computer-OU:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)

$listBox.SelectionMode = 'MultiExtended'

[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU1')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU2')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU3')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU4')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU5')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU6')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU7')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU8')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU9')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU10')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU11')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU12')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU13')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU14')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU15')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU16')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU17')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU18')

$listBox.Height = 250
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Topmost = $true

$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $OU_result = $listBox.SelectedItems
}

$OU_1 =                   "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_2 =               "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_3 =               "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_4 =                   "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_5 =                   "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_6 =                   "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_7 =                       "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_8 =                   "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_9 =                   "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_10 =                  "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_11 =              "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_12 =              "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_13 =              "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_14 =              "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_15 =              "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_16 =                      "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_17 =                      "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_18 =              "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"

if ($OU_result -eq #one of the variables above)
{
#then take the spezific string and define it as $OUpathVariable
}
Add-Computer -ComputerName $hostname -DomainName "domain.de" -OUPath $OUpathVariable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could use many if-loops like that - but there has to be a much smarter way i guess.

There *is* a smarter way!

Simply test that the input falls into the accepted range of values and then pass it directly:

```
if (@($OU_1,$OU_2,$OU_3,...,$OU_N) -contains $OU_result) {
    # valid response, proceed with the join
    Add-Computer -ComputerName $hostname -DomainName "domain.de" -OUPath $OU_result
}
else {
    # invalid OU result, fail or prompt the user again
}
```

---

If you need to *translate* the user response (eg. allow the user to pick "The IT Department OU") to a valid OU, organize the response->OU pairs into a dictionary and use that to "look up" the correct target OU:

```
$OUMapping = @{
    "IT Department" = "OU=Endpoints,OU=Computers,OU=IT,DC=domain,DC=tld"
    "Marketing"     = "OU=Computers,OU=Marketing,DC=domain,DC=tld"
    "Accounting"    = "OU=Laptops,OU=Accounting,DC=domain,DC=tld"
}
```

Then for processing the response you'd test that the mapping table contains the chosen department and grab the corresponding value:

```
if ($OUMapping.ContainsKey($OU_result)) {
    # valid response, proceed with the join with corresponding OU from mapping table
    Add-Computer -ComputerName $hostname -DomainName "domain.de" -OUPath $OUMapping[$OU_result]
}
else {
    # invalid OU result, fail or prompt the user again
}
```

Comment: Hello Mathias, thanks a lot for your answer. That is what i was looking for :) The IF-Condition `if ($OUMapping.ContainsKey($OU_result))`  didnt work so I was playin around a little bit. The following is the result - unfortunatly it is not working. `if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $OU_result = $listBox.SelectedItems
}
if ($OUMapping.Keys -contains ($OU_result))
{
 Add-Computer -NewName $hostname -DomainName "domain.de" -OUPath $OUMapping[$OU_result] -restart
}`

Comment: That is the problem: Add-Computer : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'OUPath'. Specified
method is not supported.
At line:102 char:65
+ ... ostname -DomainName "domain.de" -OUPath $OUMapping[$OU_result] -restar ...
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Computer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand

Comment: @milanh91 Change the `$OU_result = $listBox.SelectedItems` line to `$OU_result = $listBox.SelectedItems |Select -First 1`

Comment: unfortunatly no difference. I tried out some things: When i place the distinguishedName of the target OU directly in the Add-Computer command - its works. So there is no problem with the priveleges. When i declare the $OUMapping[$OU_result] Variable into another variable and place this variable into the command it doesnt work. When i Write-Output of the $OUMapping[OU_result] Variable before the add-computer command i get the correct distinguishedName. It has to be something with the $OUMapping[$OU_result] thing. ://

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Mathias R. Jessen for your help :)
i found the missing part.

`OUPath $($OUMapping[$OU_result])` - a missing **$** before the **clamp**.

Here the complete funtional script to automate the domain join:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
$hostname = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please enter 
computername", "Computername", "$env:computername")

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$OUMapping = @{
$OU_1 = "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_2 = "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_3 = "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_4 = "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_5 = "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
$OU_6 = "OU=Computer,OU=XYZ,OU=XYZ,DC=domain,DC=de"
}

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'AD-OU?'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,360)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,290)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(188,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'Start DomainJoin'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(205,290)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(65,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Select Computer OU:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)

$listBox.SelectionMode = 'MultiExtended'

[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU1')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU2')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU3')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU4')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU5')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('OU6')

$listBox.Height = 250
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Topmost = $true

$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $OU_result = $listBox.SelectedItems
}

if ($OUMapping.Keys -contains ($OU_result))
{
    Add-Computer -NewName $hostname -DomainName "domain.de" -OUPath 
    $($OUMapping[$OU_result]) -restart -force
}
```